# Magento data script and data upgrade script creation

Tags: php, magento, staging

I am working with a Magento staging server and production server. I can push updated files to the production server and edit the database with install and upgrade scripts, so I don't have to mess with the database manually.

The problem is if I apply settings or data to a new extension in staging. For example, I have installed a dealer locator with 500 dealers. Works great on the staging server. 
I can use a data script or data upgrade script to make the production server import all the data but how do I create that script from the existing data ?

Obviously manually would not be an option. Is there a way to export an extension's existing data to a Magento Upgrade data script ?

Comment: The 500 dealers have been created automatically by data install/upgrade scripts? Or have they been created manually on the staging environment?

Comment: They have been created manually in the staging environment. (Through an import function in the extension actually). 

It's actually the same for any extensions. There are settings that are done after the install that save to the database. I could do them again or import them again on the live server but sort of defeats the point of the staging and live server environments.

Comment: Ideally all of this should have been done as part of an updater. But all is not lost as I'm guessing you could simply just export the part related to your 500 dealers which should be stored in your core_config_data and import it in your production environment. To test this I would recommend: 1. save a backup of stage db; 2. extract the info from core_config_data related to the 500 dealers; 3. import prod db into stage db (without the orders, invoices and shipments); 4. apply the extracted info (see point 2); 5. test; 6. if all is ok apply data extracted at point 2 onto your production db

Comment: I assume you referring to doing that directly in myPhpAdmin. That is what I am doing at the moment but seems like a very manual way to run a staging and production server. I thought there would be a better practice to push changes to production.